# Why is Hasura suggesting an "array relationship" for a one-to-one (ie should be a object relationship)

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura

Using Hasura Cloud (v2.0.0-alpha.2.cloud.2) I have one-to-one relationship between a `Service` table and a `ServiceSettings` table, where `ServiceSettings.serviceId -> Service.id` and `ServiceSettings.serviceId` is unique.

Here is the structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "ServiceSettings" (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    --- bunch of columns ---
    "serviceId" integer NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY "ServiceSettings"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "ServiceSettings_serviceId_key" UNIQUE ("serviceId");

ALTER TABLE ONLY "ServiceSettings"
    ADD CONSTRAINT "ServiceSettings_serviceId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("serviceId") REFERENCES "Service"(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I had to manually create the object relationship on `Service`, and Hasura is still suggesting an array relationship, why????:

[image]

Comment: What version of Hasura are you using? I experienced this in the past (despite the unique key), and the solution was to put the foreign key on the other entity. But, I just tested it out with 1.3.3 and after adding the unique key it suggested an object relationship as you would expect.

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky I am using Hasura Cloud v2.0.0-alpha.2.cloud.2

Comment: Weird. Maybe it works differently in v2. I did test it out on mine, as I said, and got the expected result that you aren't getting.